# While and For in CSV import by column name

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I have a script where I upload a CSV file, it reads the column names and the value inthe column at a specific row. this is because I want to add them like

row nr, row 1 value, row 3 title, row 3 value
example:

row_nr, part_nr, length, width
1,      GL       3000,   2000
2,      FD       2500,   1500

so I'll insert in one table like this:

1, GL, length, 3000
1, GL, width, 2000
2, FD, length, 2500
2, FD, width, 1500

and so on...

the problem is that I don't know how many columns  visitor will have so I need a while or for, I don't want to define it by hand under a limit.

```
 <?php
include 'db_xls.php';

$cookie_name = "Draft ID";
$cookie_value = "John Doe";
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day


$date = date_create();
$timestamp=date_timestamp_get($date);
echo $timestamp;
if(isset($_POST["Import"])){


        echo $filename=$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];

        }


$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("$filename", "r")) !== FALSE)
{
    echo '<table>';

    // Get headers
    if (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ',')) !== FALSE)
    {
        //$cap_tabel=array($data);



        $cota0=$data[0];
        $cota1=$data[1];
        $cota2=$data[2];
        $cota3=$data[3];
        $cota4=$data[4];
        $cota5=$data[5];
        $cota6=$data[6];
        $cota7=$data[7];
        $cota8=$data[8];
        $cota9=$data[9];
        $cota10=$data[10];
        $cota11=$data[11];
        $cota12=$data[12];
        $cota13=$data[13];
        $cota14=$data[14];
        $cota15=$data[15];
        $cota16=$data[16];
        $cota17=$data[17];
        $cota18=$data[18];
        $cota19=$data[19];
        $cota20=$data[20];
        $cota21=$data[21];
        $cota22=$data[22];
        $cota23=$data[23];
        $cota24=$data[24];
        $cota25=$data[25];
        $cota26=$data[26];
        $cota27=$data[27];
        $cota28=$data[28];
        $cota29=$data[29];
        $cota30=$data[30];
        $cota31=$data[31];
        $cota32=$data[32];
        $cota33=$data[33];
        $cota34=$data[34];
        $cota35=$data[35];
        $cota36=$data[36];
        $cota37=$data[37];
        $cota38=$data[38];
        $cota39=$data[39];
        $cota40=$data[40];
        $cota41=$data[41];
        $cota42=$data[42];
        $cota43=$data[43];
        $cota44=$data[44];
        $cota45=$data[45];
        $cota46=$data[46];
        $cota47=$data[47];
        $cota48=$data[48];
        $cota49=$data[49];
        $cota50=$data[50];
    }
    $rand=0;
    // Get the rest
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ',')) !== FALSE)
    {

        //echo '<tr><td>'.implode('</td><td>', $data).'</td></tr>';

        $rand=$rand+1;
        echo '<tr><td>rand:'.$rand.'</td>';
        echo '<tr><td>'.$cota0.':'.$data[0].'</td>';
        echo '<tr><td>'.$cota1.':'.$data[1].'</td>';


echo "<hr>";        
        echo '<tr><td>rand:'.$rand.'</td>';
        echo '<tr><td>'.$cota0.':'.$data[0].'</td>';
        echo '<tr><td>'.$cota2.':'.$data[2].'</td>';



echo "<hr>";        
        echo '<tr><td>rand:'.$rand.'</td>';
        echo '<tr><td>'.$cota0.':'.$data[0].'</td>';
        echo '<tr><td>'.$cota3.':'.$data[3].'</td>';


        /*

        echo 'RAND:'.$rand.'</br>';
        echo 'COD PIESA'.$data[0].'</br>';
        echo ''.$cota1.':'.$data[1].'</br>';
        echo ''.$cota2.':'.$data[2].'</br>';
        echo ''.$cota3.':'.$data[3].'</br>';
        echo ''.$cota4.':'.$data[4].'</br>';
        echo ''.$cota5.':'.$data[5].'</br>';
        echo ''.$cota6.':'.$data[6].'</br>';
        echo ''.$cota7.':'.$data[7].'</br>';
        echo ''.$cota8.':'.$data[8].'</br>';
        echo ''.$cota9.':'.$data[9].'</br>';
        echo ''.$cota10.':'.$data[10].'</br>';*/

        //  $sInsertSql = "INSERT INTO `r45815ar_zeu`.`z_fab_importdraft` (`z_fab_imp_draftID`, `add_ip`, `add_id`, `add_datetime`, `user_id`, `amount`, `currency`, `item`, `transaction_status`, `external_transaction_id`, `transaction_type`) VALUES (NULL, '$add_ip', '$user_id', '$add_datetime', '$user_id', '$amount', '$currency', '$item_number', '$status_tranzaction', '$id_tranzaction_extern', 'Deposit')";
//$GLOBALS["conn"]->Execute($sInsertSql);
    }
    fclose($handle);
    //echo '</table>';
}
?>
```

Can you please help me to add a for or while for header and for the column name and value keeping the row number and part number like in my example?

Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I posted a gist for you on fb, 
have a look at it.
[gist](https://gist.github.com/snevin/4933f8e5b92968a2da54c2deeb8a9a63)

It is based on the info you provided on fb.
once you parse the csv file all you need to do is loop thru the data and make sql statements as needed.

I didnt consider you wont know the col names or how many, shouldnt be to hard though!

After `csv_to_array()` function

```
/**
 * Example
 */
$contents = csv_to_array('example.csv');

/**
 * DEBUG
*/ 
echo "<pre>";
print_r($contents);
echo "</pre>";

// generate your temp Id for the inserts, 
$tempId = uniqid('', false);

// loop thru the data
foreach ($contents as $k=>$v){

    //Optional -  clean up whitespaces in the array keys
    $keys = str_replace(' ', '', array_keys($contents[$k]));

    $contents[$k] = array_combine($keys, array_values( $contents[$k]));

    // no need to manipulate the array, only need to know what you need to insert
    $cod_piesa = $contents[$k]['cod_piesa'];

    // dont need this anymore
    unset($contents[$k]['cod_piesa']);

    // now loop thru the headers
    foreach($contents[$k] as $header => $value){
        // white spaces again 
        $value = trim($value);
        //make the statements   
        $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_drafts (draft_id, row, cod_piesa, header, value)
                                VALUES ('$tempId', '$k', '$cod_piesa', '$header', '$value');";

        // execute your statment...

        /**
         * DEBUG
         */
         echo "$sql <br>";
    }
}
// redirect for review with header()
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16533008)

Comment: My bad, I am new here. I added some code! Hopefully that makes it easier to solve.

Comment: Hi, this is almost working, the only issue is that the INSERT SQL is not reusing the part code. is just left blank:

Comment: Silly me, the header was case sensitive for part name. it works.

Answer (score 1):

Based in your answer below, it seems that all you need is to read a CSV file and insert it a database table:

```
<?php
$file = "your.csv";
$body = [];

if (($handle = fopen($file, "r")) !== FALSE) {
  while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
     $body[] = $data;
  }
  fclose($handle);
}

$sqlData = serialize($body);
$query = "INSERT INTO files (data) VALUES(${sqlData});";
// execute query...
```

Comment: Thank you. It might work but I don't know where to put it, also as I need to use it again when I do the insert below in that while.

Comment: echo $data1[$i] . " - " . $data2[$i];
Warning: Unterminated comment starting line 38 in /home/r45815arod/public_html/zeu/xls.php on line 38

Comment: Hi, it is indeed a CSV but you don't know the names of columns or their possition or how many they are. this is why I convert it into a list...

Comment: If you don't know anything about the file, it is unlikely you will have SQL tables for each attribute - why not saving the content of the file as a serialized array? (see updated answer)

Answer (score 0):

This is the CSV style:

```
COD_PIESA   LUNGIME LATIME  GROSIME CANTITATE   UM
GL          1500    500     50      1           BUC
FD          1600    600     60      2           ROLE
MM          1700    700     70      3           KG
TL          1800    800     80      4           M3
```

And I want to insert into  SQL like:

```
ROW COD_PIESA   COLUMN      VALUE
1   GL          LUNGIME     1500
1   GL          LATIME      500
1   GL          GROSIME     50
1   GL          CANTITATE   1
1   GL          UM          BUC
2   FD          LUNGIME     1600
…   …           …           …
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Javier,

I've managed to sort it but to be honest is too much to be made by hand. If I'll leave it to 50 rows maximum number of columns, I can do it by hand. It works perfectly as it is but I have too many inserts:

```
    if (($handle = fopen("$filename", "r")) !== FALSE)
{
    echo '<table>';

    // Get headers
    if (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ',')) !== FALSE)
    {
        //$cap_tabel=array($data);




        $cota0=$data[0];
        $cota1=$data[1];
        $cota2=$data[2];
        $cota3=$data[3];
        $cota4=$data[4];
        $cota5=$data[5];
        $cota6=$data[6];
        $cota7=$data[7];
        $cota8=$data[8];
........
$cota50=$data[50];
    }
    $rand=0;
    // Get the rest
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ',')) !== FALSE)
    {

//coloana 1
        $rand=$rand+1;
        echo '<tr><td>rand:'.$rand.'</td>';
        $piesa=$data[0];
        $cota=$cota1;
        $valoare_cota=$data[1];

echo '<tr><td>ROW:'.$rand.'</td>';
echo '<tr><td>PART:'.$piesa.'</td>';
echo '<tr><td>'.$cota.':'.$valoare_cota.'</td>';

        //add coloana 1


    $coloana1 = "INSERT INTO `r45815ar_zeu`.`z_fab_importdraft`
    (`z_fab_imp_recID`, `z_fab_imp_draftID`, `z_fab_imp_UserID`, `z_fab_imp_AddDT`, `z_fab_imp_Rand`, `z_fab_imp_Piesa`, `z_fab_imp_Cota`, `z_fab_imp_Valoarea`) VALUES
    (NULL, '$draft_ID', '$user_id', '$date_time', '$rand', '$piesa', '$cota', '$valoare_cota')";


    mysql_query($coloana1) or die(mysql_error());



//if column 2 exists
//coloana 2

$cota=$cota2;
$valoare_cota=$data[2];

if ($cota!='')

{

$coloana2 = "INSERT INTO `r45815ar_zeu`.`z_fab_importdraft`
    (`z_fab_imp_recID`, `z_fab_imp_draftID`, `z_fab_imp_UserID`, `z_fab_imp_AddDT`, `z_fab_imp_Rand`, `z_fab_imp_Piesa`, `z_fab_imp_Cota`, `z_fab_imp_Valoarea`) VALUES
    (NULL, '$draft_ID', '$user_id', '$date_time', '$rand', '$piesa', '$cota', '$valoare_cota')";


    mysql_query($coloana2) or die(mysql_error());

echo 'insert col 2';
}
else
{
echo "empty col 2";    }


//daca exista coloana 3
//coloana 3

$cota=$cota3;
$valoare_cota=$data[3];

if ($cota!='')

{

$coloana3 = "INSERT INTO `r45815ar_zeu`.`z_fab_importdraft`
    (`z_fab_imp_recID`, `z_fab_imp_draftID`, `z_fab_imp_UserID`, `z_fab_imp_AddDT`, `z_fab_imp_Rand`, `z_fab_imp_Piesa`, `z_fab_imp_Cota`, `z_fab_imp_Valoarea`) VALUES
    (NULL, '$draft_ID', '$user_id', '$date_time', '$rand', '$piesa', '$cota', '$valoare_cota')";


    mysql_query($coloana3) or die(mysql_error());

echo 'insert col 3';
}
else
{
echo "empty col 3";
}
```

This will work as I want, the problem is that I define too many inserts etc, without using a while or for which I can't figure out where to put it.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add an answer as I'm sure google will index this and there will be people searching for a solution like this one.

This is a PHP script that works when you try to upload a CSV file, and create a list instead of columns import.
It keeps the first column and row number as a refference for future use. You might have a list of components, so you need the row number where it is in case they repeat.

You can use it to have a table with components and specification for them like width, depth, thickness or whatever you want to have in the columns.

John's answer solved my problem after days and days of research online so I want to give him all the credit for this.

Brilliant job! thank you!